# Convertir todos los XSD de una carpeta a código JAVA?

Tags: java, xml

Lo que sucede es que cuento con una gran cantidad de archivos XSD que tienen todo lo que necesito , pero necesito transformarlas a código JAVA use el JAXB Binding pero solo me permite de uno en uno.

Comment: Si podrías compartir el código que ya usas para transformarlas sería más fácil de ayudarte. Java es touring completo, así si puedes con uno, puedes con todos ;)

Comment: Estoy usando netbeans , basicamente sigo esto https://netbeans.org/kb/74/websvc/jaxb.html

Answer (score 1):

Prueba la herramienta [xjc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html) incluida en el JDK.

```
xjc *.xsd
```

Si usas Maven, el [plugin JAXB2](https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home) tambien te puede servir para generar codigo fuente Java antes de compilar.